# SQL View displaying current status of a "unit" for every date that something changes with the "unit"

Tags: sql, t-sql

In a project I'm working on, there is a table of units and then there are several tables that pertain to the units' locations at a given point in time as well as other factors for a given point in time.

For example, Unit1 might be at LocationA on 1/1/2009 and have a second location entry that has Unit1 at LocationB on 3/1/2010. Likewise, Unit1 might be Size1 on 2/20/2009 and Size2 on 1/12/2010.

Table Structures

```
Table: Unit  
int ID (identity, PK)  
varchar Name  

Table: Unit_Location  
int OrgID (FK Unit.ID)  
datetime eff_date  
int LocationID (FK Location.ID)  

Table: Unit_Size  
int OrgID (FK Unit.ID)  
datetime eff_date  
int UnitSizeID (FK Size.ID)
```

I want to have a view that takes all of the changes from the various property change tables and has row for every date that the unit is different and have the current values for all the properties in that row. So for the example listed above, the view would like:

```
1/1/2009  - Unit1 - LocationA - Null  
2/20/2009 - Unit1 - LocationA - Size1  
1/12/2010 - Unit1 - LocationA - Size2  
3/1/2010  - Unit1 - LocationB - Size2
```

If I do a full outer join based on the effective dates, I believe I can easily get to:

```
1/1/2009  - Unit1 - LocationA - Null  
2/20/2009 - Unit1 - Null      - Size1  
1/12/2010 - Unit1 - Null      - Size2  
3/1/2010  - Unit1 - LocationB - Null
```

But that doesn't quite get me to what I want. What should my SQL look like to get a view with the full status of every Unit for every date that something with the unit changes? `enter code here`

Comment: It is impossible to answer this with any degree of accuracy without seeing the structure of the table/s you are selecting from.

Comment: I updated with the table structures of interest. I didn't include it before because I wasn't sure how to format it nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give this a try:

```
--I added more test data :-)
DECLARE @Unit table (ID int identity(1,1) primary key  ,Name  varchar(10))
INSERT INTO @Unit (Name) VALUES ('Unit 1')
INSERT INTO @Unit (Name) VALUES ('Unit 2')

DECLARE @Unit_Location table (OrgID int,eff_date datetime,Location varchar(10))
INSERT INTO @Unit_Location VALUES (1,'01/01/2009','LocationA')
INSERT INTO @Unit_Location VALUES (1,'03/01/2010','LocationB')
INSERT INTO @Unit_Location VALUES (2,'03/03/2010','Locationz')

DECLARE @Unit_Size table (OrgID int, eff_date datetime, UnitSize varchar(10))
INSERT INTO @Unit_Size VALUES (1,'02/20/2009','Size1')
INSERT INTO @Unit_Size VALUES (1,'01/12/2010','Size2')
INSERT INTO @Unit_Size VALUES (2,'01/02/2010','Size9')


;WITH AllDates AS
(
    SELECT OrgID,eff_date FROM @Unit_Location
    UNION 
    SELECT OrgID,eff_date FROM @Unit_Size

), AllPKs AS
(
SELECT 
    a.OrgID,a.eff_date
    ,(SELECT MAX(l.eff_date) FROM @Unit_Location l WHERE l.eff_date<=a.eff_date AND a.OrgID=l.OrgID) AS LocationPK
    ,(SELECT MAX(s.eff_date) FROM @Unit_Size     s WHERE s.eff_date<=a.eff_date AND a.OrgID=s.OrgID) AS SizePK
    FROM AllDates a
)
SELECT
    a.eff_date, u.Name, l.Location, s.UnitSize
    FROM AllPKs                        a
        LEFT OUTER JOIN @Unit          u ON a.OrgID=u.ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN @Unit_Location l ON a.LocationPK=l.eff_date AND a.OrgID=l.OrgID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN @Unit_Size     s ON a.SizePK=s.eff_date AND a.OrgID=s.OrgID
    ORDER BY u.Name,a.eff_date
```

OUTPUT:

```
eff_date                Name       Location   UnitSize
----------------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
2009-01-01 00:00:00.000 Unit 1     LocationA  NULL
2009-02-20 00:00:00.000 Unit 1     LocationA  Size1
2010-01-12 00:00:00.000 Unit 1     LocationA  Size2
2010-03-01 00:00:00.000 Unit 1     LocationB  Size2
2010-01-02 00:00:00.000 Unit 2     NULL       Size9
2010-03-03 00:00:00.000 Unit 2     Locationz  Size9

(6 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: This wasn't working at first and was giving me far too many results. After looking at what was happening, I figured out that it was just missing an "AND a.OrgID=l.OrgID" etc... for the bottom left outer joins. This did not cause an issue with your test data because none of your dates are the same. Thanks so much for your help! I'll mark this as the answer but recommend you make the modification I mentioned to make it complete.